# What is this trilobite-like creature?

Tags: species-identification, limnology

This was found under a rock in a freshwater creek in Maryland. Stayed like this for while, then stretched out long, then contracted, and then JUMPED off the rock back into the water. Looks like a trilobite. Rock-colored.

[image]

Comment: well I don't know of any freshwater chitons, so I'm going with a leech. In fact, if by "stretched out long" you mean it literally became long like a ribbon, then this is almost certainly a leech.

Comment: Yes, a leech. I don't know the species, or even family.

Comment: Very nice image of a leech (probably of family [Glossiphoniidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossiphoniidae)). Please consider sharing a cropped version somewhere like [iNaturalist.org](https://www.inaturalist.org/)

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Never seen a leech before. I always assumed they were more squishy-looking!